# How can I display the duplicates in a listbox by using a button c#

Tags: c#, file, listbox, directory, duplicates

I cannot find a answer to this sort of problem anywhere on the internet so I figured I might as well ask myself. I need to be able press a button that will then run a function that searches the file directory chosen and all of the subfolders after to see if the same file is there twice. I will put all of the necessary code below:

```
public partial class fileForm : Form
{
        private string _filelistlocation;
        private string _fileDest;
        private string _fileSource;

        public fileForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }


public void fileForm_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
            _filelistlocation = textBox1.Text;
            _fileDest = labelDestRoot.Text;
            _fileSource = labelSourceRoot.Text;
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
            checkedListBox1.Items.Clear();
            listBox2.Items.Clear();
            ReadFromList();
}

private void GetDuplicates()
{
            DirectoryInfo directoryToCheck = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\temp\Location Source");`

            FileInfo[] files = directoryToCheck.GetFiles("*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
            var duplicates = files.GroupBy(x => x.Name)
                                    .Where(group => group.Count() > 1)
                                    .Select(group => group.Key);//display duplicates
            if (duplicates.Count() > 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("No Dupes");
                FileStream s2 = new FileStream(_filelistlocation, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read);
            }
            else
                listBox1.Items.Add(duplicates);`
        }

private void button5_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
             GetDuplicates();
}
```

EDIT:
`private void GetDuplicates()
        {
            DirectoryInfo directoryToCheck = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\temp\Location Source");

```
        FileInfo[] files = directoryToCheck.GetFiles("*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
        var duplicates = files.GroupBy(x => x.Name)
                                .Where(group => group.Count() > 1)
                                .Select(group => group.Key);//display duplicates
        if (!duplicates.Any())
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add(duplicates);

            FileStream s2 = new FileStream(_filelistlocation, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read);



        }
        else
            MessageBox.Show("No Dupes");
    }`
```

like this?

EDIT 2:

```
private void GetDuplicates()
    {
        DirectoryInfo directoryToCheck = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\temp\Location Source");

        FileInfo[] files = directoryToCheck.GetFiles("*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
        var duplicates = files.GroupBy(x => x.Name)
                                .Where(group => group.Count() > 1)
                                .Select(group => group.Key);//display duplicates
        if (!duplicates.Any())
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add(duplicates.ToArray());

            FileStream s2 = new FileStream(_filelistlocation, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read);



        }
        else
            MessageBox.Show("No Dupes");
    }
```

If anyone could help that would be nice. Thanks!

Comment: What is the problem that you are facing with the posted code?

Comment: When I click the button the message box pops up saying " no dupes" whereas what I am testing defiantly has duplicates.

Comment: Because you are displaying the message at if block it should be at else block.

Comment: if (duplicates.Count() > 0) should be if (!duplicates.Any())

Comment: I changed it and now in the listbox it shows this "System.Linq.Enumerable Iterator`2[System.Linq}...

Comment: I have added a edit to the question, it still pops up with no dupes.

Comment: Use `listBox1.Items.AddRange(duplicates.ToArray())`

Comment: Still shows as "No Dupes"

Comment: You need to apply both changes - the condition mentioned by @HariPrasad and my previous comment

Comment: Like how it is in edit 2?

Comment: I tried what you guys said but sadly it didn't work. Check out @Dmitry Bychenko 's answer. That worked after about 3 attempts. Thank you anyways

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
  // Fluent: given directory name obtain duplicates with no temporarys
  var duplicates = Directory
    .EnumerateFiles(@"C:\temp\Location Source", "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
    .GroupBy(file => Path.GetFileName(file))
    .Where(chunk => chunk.Count() > 1)
    .Select(chunk => chunk.Key);

  // Straightforward: are there ANY duplicates?
  if (duplicates.Any()) { 
    // Please note "AddRange" (you have many items to add)
    listBox1.Items.AddRange(duplicates.ToArray());

    //TODO: may be it should be put into "else" (no dups)
    // Looks that you've forgot to wrap IDisposable into using...
    using (FileStream s2 = new FileStream(_filelistlocation, 
      FileMode.Open, 
      FileAccess.Read, 
      FileShare.Read)) {
      ...
    }
  }
  else {
    MessageBox.Show("No Dupes");
  }
```

Comment: @Robert Vasistha: I'm sorry for typos: it should be `chunk.Count()` instead of `chunk.Count` and `AddRange(duplicates.ToArray())` instead of  just `AddRange(duplicates)`; I've edited the answer

Comment: What the heck! It actually worked?! I'm kinda surprised and confused as I already had .Toarray() and .count(0 from before yet when I tried again it worked? I think it could have been indentation but visual studio would have told me if it was that. Anyways thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Based on comments, you are displaying "**No dupes**" message when there are duplicates. *Invert* your `if` statment

```
if (duplicates.Count() <= 0)
{
    MessageBox.Show("No Dupes");
    FileStream s2 = new FileStream(_filelistlocation, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read);
}
else
{
    listBox1.Items.AddRange(duplicates);
}
```